# I want change page heading position

Tags: joomla

In Joomla Page heading showing inside of an article I want to change the position of page heading, is it possible to customize page heading position?

I had included following code in **template/protostar/index.php**

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading', 1)) : ?>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?> </h1>
    </div>
    <?php endif;
if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && !$this->item->paginationposition && $this->item->paginationrelative)
{
    echo $this->item->pagination;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to add this code in **template/protostar/index.php** <?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading')) : ?>
 <div class="page-header"><h1> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?> </h1></div><?php endif; ?>

Comment: Yes but which code? We can't help debug your issue if we can't see any code. Please edit your question with the code you were using

Comment: in **template/protostar/index.php** <?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading', 1)) : ?>
 <div class="page-header">
  <h1> <?php echo  $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?> </h1>
 </div>
 <?php endif;?>

Comment: As requested, please **edit your question** with code updates. Don't write it in the comments as it's harder to read. You also need to mention what the code you're currently using results in.

Comment: What happens now? Does it throw error or not work as expected?

Comment: Where did you get this code from? My guess is that this code will not work inside the templates index.php. You are outside the scope

Comment: I have specify title under menu item **Browser Page Title** please check the attached screeshot

Comment: sorry, I cannot attached the screenshot because I don't have 10 reputation

Answer (score 1):

**What you can do:**
Just update one of the css files in the correct template to display the header correctly. If the header should only be reformatted on some pages and not all then you should be using different templates.

**What you should do:**
Otherwise (if you want to change the php instead) you can override the components/com_content/views/article/default.php using the [standard joomla override method](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).

You can do both the above if necessary.

You should not need to override the index.php of your template in order to do this. However if you really want to i would use the code

```
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    echo $article->get("title");
}
```

Sorry if you want more you need to give more :)

PS. I am on joomla 2.5 but i know that for joomla 3 it is more or less the same thing.

Sources: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=525350 
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Protostar is a Joomla 3.x template and `JRequest` has deprecated in Joomla 3.x ;)

Comment: Thanks @Lodder for the info. The code needs a little tweaking then but you get the idea.